# Change size of element in SegmentedPicker

Tags: swiftui

Let's say I have this simple `Picker` in a `SegmentedPickerStyle`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var favoriteColor = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $favoriteColor, label: Text("bla bla...")) {
                Text("This is a very long string").tag(0)
                Text("B").tag(1)
                Text("C").tag(2)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

the result will be something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to make the size of the segments dynamic? So that the first segment will be bigger and "B" and "C" are adjusted to it?

Comment: No, this is not possible. What you can do is creating your own segmented picker.

Comment: @Erik: It is not difficult to make it in custom way, try make it and if you got problem come back with your question.